# Decimal to Hexadecimal & binary converter Batch program, Any suggestions how to implement it differently?

Tags: batch-file

Ive been working on this decimal to hexadecimal and binary converter, the hexadecimal converts the decimal number into hex, and the binary converter does it's job.

This works just fine, but is there a different way to implement this code?

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:Main
setlocal
cls
set /p decIn=enter Decimal value: 
call :DectoHex %decIn% hexOut
call :DectoBin %decIn% binOut
echo !hexOut!
echo !binOut!
pause>nul
goto :main
endlocal

::-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

:DectoHex
set /a A=%1
set map=0123456789ABCDEF
set H=

:Hexloop
set /a B=!A! %%16 & set /a A /=16 
set H=!map:~%B%,1!!H!
if !A! gtr 0 goto :Hexloop
set %2=!H!
goto :eof

::-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

:DectoBin
:: Note Dec Bit Bin (DBB)

set /a Dec=%1
set Bin=
for /L %%i in (1,1,32) do (
    set /a "Bit=Dec&1, Dec>>=1"
    set Bin=!Bit!!Bin!
)


:skimming
    if %Bin:~0,1% == 0 (
    set Bin=%Bin:~1% & goto :skimming

)

set %2=!Bin!
goto :eof

::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

:BintoDec
set bin=11011
set dig=
set digval=1

set dec=

:Loop
if %bin% gtr 1 (
    set dig=%bin:~-1%
    set bin=%bin:~0,-1%
) else (
    set /a dig=%bin%
    set bin=0
)

if %dig% equ 1 (
    set /a dec+=%digval%
)
set digval *=2

if %bin% gtr 0 goto :loop

echo %dec%

pause>nul

goto :eof
```

The main function recieves an input from the user and passes the variable as a parameter to a hexadecimal converter and a binary converter, the

Comment: Since the algorythm stays the same you could pass the base to convert to and have only one subroutine.

Comment: This question is more suitable for [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than for Stack Overflow as the code is already working good as long as the user really enters a decimal number (or a hexadecimal number starting with `0x` or an octal number starting with `0`).

Answer (score 3):

To convert to/from any number base between 2 and 36:

```
:: Q:\Test\2017\09\16\SO_46254352.cmd
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set map=0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

:Main
cls
set "DecIn="
set /p DecIn=enter value: 
if not defined DecIn goto :Eof
Set /A DecIn=DecIn

call :Dec2Base  2 %DecIn%  BaseOut
call :Base2Dec  2 %BaseOut% DecBack
echo DecBack=%DecBack%  Base  2=%BaseOut%

call :Dec2Base 16 %DecIn%  BaseOut
call :Base2Dec 16 %BaseOut% DecBack
echo DecBack=%DecBack%  Base 16=%BaseOut%

call :Dec2Base 32 %DecIn%  BaseOut
call :Base2Dec 32 %BaseOut% DecBack
echo DecBack=%DecBack%  Base 32=%BaseOut%

goto :main
::-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Dec2Base Base DecIn BaseOut
Setlocal
Echo:%2|findstr /i "^[%map:~0,10%]*$" >Nul 2>&1 ||(Echo invalid char for base 10&Goto :Eof)
set /a Num=%2
set "Ret="

:Dec2BaseLoop
set /a "Digit=Num %% %1"
set /a "Num /= %1"
set Ret=!map:~%Digit%,1!%Ret%
if "%Num%" neq "0" goto :Dec2BaseLoop
Endlocal&Set "%3=%Ret%"&Goto :Eof
::-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

:Base2Dec Base BaseIn DecBack
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set /A "Base=%1,PlaceVal=1,Ret=0"
Echo:%2|findstr /i "^[!map:,%Base%!]*$" >Nul 2>&1 ||(Echo invalid char for base %1&Goto :Eof)
Set Val=%2

:Base2DecLoop
Set "Digit=%Val:~-1%"
If %Digit% Leq 9 goto :Next
For /L %%i in (10,1,%Base%) Do If /i "!Digit!" Equ "!map:~%%i,1!" (Set "Digit=%%i" & Goto :Next )
Echo Something went wrong & Pause

:Next
set /A "Ret+=Digit * PlaceVal,PlaceVal *= Base"
Set "Val=%Val:~0,-1%"
If defined Val goto :Base2DecLoop
Endlocal & Set "%3=%Ret%" & Goto :Eof
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2017\09\16\SO_46254352.cmd
enter value: 4095
DecBack=4095  Base  2=111111111111
DecBack=4095  Base 16=FFF
DecBack=4095  Base 32=3VV
enter value: 0xBadAffe
DecBack=195932158  Base  2=1011101011011010111111111110
DecBack=195932158  Base 16=BADAFFE
DecBack=195932158  Base 32=5QRBVU
```

Comment: could you please explain the significance of the following line? Echo:%2|findstr /i "^[%map:~0,10%]*$" >Nul 2>&1 ||(Echo invalid char for base 10&Goto :Eof)

Comment: As I later added the command `set /a DecIN=Decin` (to allow Hex input) it has no more significance. This will strip invalid chars (being interpreted as vars). The intention was to check if the complete input is in the range of digits matching the number base.

Answer (score 0):

In a function, it gaves that.

(Put in in a UTF-8 .txt file with BOM EFBBBF, first line must be blank)

```
cls
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"
chcp 65001 >nul
set title_script=Base conversion
title %title_script%

set "decimal_number=200"
set "result_hexadecimal="
call :function_change_base_number 10 decimal_number 16 result_hexadecimal
echo %decimal_number% base 10 = %result_hexadecimal% base 16
echo.

set "octal_number=310"
set "result_binary="
call :function_change_base_number 8 octal_number 2 result_binary
echo %octal_number% base 8 = %result_binary% base 2
echo.

set "quaternary_number=3020"
set "base_36_result="
call :function_change_base_number 4 quaternary_number 36 base_36_result
echo %quaternary_number% base 4 = %base_36_result% base 36
echo.

pause
exit

:function_change_base_number
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set /a input_base=%~1
    set input_number=!%~2!
    set /a output_base=%~3

    rem UCase
    for %%i in ("a=A" "b=B" "c=C" "d=D" "e=E" "f=F" "g=G" "h=H" "i=I" "j=J" "k=K" "l=L" "m=M" "n=N" "o=O" "p=P" "q=Q" "r=R" "s=S" "t=T" "u=U" "v=V" "w=W" "x=X" "y=Y" "z=Z") do (
        call set "input_number=!input_number:%%~i!"
    )

    set map=0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
    set map_base=!map:~0,%input_base%!
    set /a position=0
    set input_number_check=%input_number%
    :loop_1
        set current_map_base_character=!map_base:~%position%,1!
        set input_number_check=!input_number_check:%current_map_base_character%=!
        if "!input_number_check!" == "" goto next_1
        set /a position+=1
        if "!map_base:~%position%,1!" NEQ "" goto loop_1
        echo Error.
        echo Invalid character in base %input_base%.
        echo.
        pause
        exit
    :next_1

    set /a carry_flag=1
    set "input_number_tmp=%input_number%"
    set "result_decimal="
    :loop_2
        set "input_number_tmp_digit=%input_number_tmp:~-1%"
        if %input_number_tmp_digit% LEQ 9 goto next_2
        for /l %%i in (10,1,%input_base%) do (
            if /i "%input_number_tmp_digit%" EQU "!map:~%%i,1!" (
                set "input_number_tmp_digit=%%i"
                goto :next_2
            )
        )
        echo Error.
    :next_2
    set /a result_decimal+=input_number_tmp_digit * carry_flag
    set /a carry_flag *= input_base
    set "input_number_tmp=%input_number_tmp:~0,-1%"
    if defined input_number_tmp goto :loop_2

    set /a input_number_tmp=%result_decimal%
    set "result="
    :loop_3
        set /a "division_remainder=input_number_tmp %% !output_base!"
        set /a "input_number_tmp /= !output_base!"
        set result=!map:~%division_remainder%,1!%result%
        if "%input_number_tmp%" NEQ "0" goto loop_3
    endlocal & set %~4=%result%
goto :eof
```